# Next "specific" observation carried backward (NOCB)

Tags: r, dplyr, locf

This is my data frame:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:4, each = 4), 
  status = c(
    NA, "a", "c", "a", 
    NA, "c", "c", "c",
    NA, NA, "a", "c",
    NA, NA, "c", "c"),
  otherVar = letters[1:16],
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

For the variable status I want the next observation to be carried backward within group (id).

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% na.locf(fromLast = TRUE) %>% ungroup
```

However, I want only my "c" 's to be carried backwards but not "a" 's.

From variable status:

> NA  "a" "c" "a" NA  "c" "c" "c" NA  NA  "a" "c" NA  NA  "c" "c"

I want to get:

> NA  "a" "c" "a" "c"  "c" "c" "c" NA  NA  "a" "c" "c"  "c"  "c" "c"

Respectively:

```
data.frame(
  id = rep(1:4, each = 4), 
  status = c(
    NA, "a", "c", "a", 
    "c", "c", "c", "c",
    NA, NA, "a", "c",
    "c", "c", "c", "c"),
  otherVar = letters[1:16],
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After applying `na.locf0` check each position that was `NA` and if it is now `a` reset it back to `NA`.  If you want to overwrite `status` then replace the second `status2=` line with `status = if_else(is.na(status) & status2 == "a", NA_character_, status2), status2 = NULL) %>%`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(status2 = na.locf0(status, fromLast = TRUE),
         status2 = if_else(is.na(status) & status2 == "a", NA_character_, status2)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
      id status otherVar status2
   <int> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  
 1     1 <NA>   a        <NA>   
 2     1 a      b        a      
 3     1 c      c        c      
 4     1 a      d        a      
 5     2 <NA>   e        c      
 6     2 c      f        c      
 7     2 c      g        c      
 8     2 c      h        c      
 9     3 <NA>   i        <NA>   
10     3 <NA>   j        <NA>   
11     3 a      k        a      
12     3 c      l        c      
13     4 <NA>   m        c      
14     4 <NA>   n        c      
15     4 c      o        c      
16     4 c      p        c
```

Comment: I guess with na.locf inside mutate, it's safer to have na.rm=FALSE to avoid getting shorter output than input. I mean `na.locf(c(NA, "c", NA), fromLast=TRUE)`

Comment: That situation did not occur in the sample input so I assumed it does not occur in the data but  now that you have pointed it out I have changed it to `na.locf0` just in case.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `tidyr:fill` be based on creating a `dummyStatus` column. `fill` the `dummyStatus` using `.direction = "up"`. Now use this `dummyStatus` to populate `NA` values in actual `status` column after verifying the check that following value should be `c`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(dummyStatus = status) %>%
    fill(dummyStatus, .direction = "up" ) %>%
    mutate(status = ifelse(is.na(status) & lead(dummyStatus)=="c","c",status)) %>%
    select(-dummyStatus) %>% as.data.frame()

  #    id status otherVar
  # 1   1   <NA>        a
  # 2   1      a        b
  # 3   1      c        c
  # 4   1      a        d
  # 5   2      c        e
  # 6   2      c        f
  # 7   2      c        g
  # 8   2      c        h
  # 9   3   <NA>        i
  # 10  3   <NA>        j
  # 11  3      a        k
  # 12  3      c        l
  # 13  4      c        m
  # 14  4      c        n
  # 15  4      c        o
  # 16  4      c        p
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:4, each = 4), 
  status = c(
    NA, "a", "c", "a", 
    NA, "c", "c", "c",
    NA, NA, "a", "c",
    NA, NA, "c", "c"),
  otherVar = letters[1:16],
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```